# Cannot undo sudo chmod 655 /

Tags: sudo, root, chmod

I've accidentally run 'sudo chmod 655 /', and now I cannot undo this operation again because I cannot access sudo anymore. I'd actually wanted the permission to be set to 755. Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: You should not be changing permissions of system files, it almost always causes breakage. What are you trying to accomplish ? You will have to reset the permissions using a live CD.

Comment: I was going to disable browsing to the root directory by other users, but I typo'd the 7, and tried this before I actually did any changing which I ended up doing anyway =S

Comment: You can not really do that, as you can see. Users need at least ro access to most of /

Comment: I agree, it was a very dumb thing to even try. I mananged to get it back to default by booting in recovery mode, dropping to root prompt and chmodding / back to 755. That gave me a scare though =S

Comment: OK, lesson learned. You might be interested in tools such as apparmor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into a Ubuntu live CD or USB flash drive, and run your command from there. This should fix the permissions on your root folder.

```
sudo chmod /path/to/root/ 755
```