# I run the chmod command on /. Folder and my laptop hang

Tags: permissions

I run the followimg command  on my and laptop hang. then i turn the power off and start it again since then it is saying run in low graphics mode bt its not working

```
ayush@inspiron# chmod -x /.
```

so please tell me how to fix it
i also tried recovery mode bt doesn't work

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it boots. Why did you run this command? Perhaps chmod +x / will help you. Perhaps not. In fact, I believe that after messing with system THAT much the healthiest option is reinstalling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot undo sudo chmod 655 /](http://askubuntu.com/questions/352436/cannot-undo-sudo-chmod-655)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i reinstalled the ubuntu again.Actually i was trying to run a kali tool in ubuntu and  i was providing permissions and accidentally   ended with it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [linked post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352436/cannot-undo-sudo-chmod-655) will help you a bit.

Use a Live CD and mount your root partition (e.g. `/dev/sda1`).

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Execute `chmod +x`:

```
chmod +x /mnt/*
```

However, I would only use this emergency fix to get all my data from the system. Best advice is to get your data off and re-install Ubuntu. I'm not sure Linux will recover nicely from this.